# How to find an isomorphism between these graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, planar-graphs

[graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LDpY.png)

How to find an isomorphism between these graphs?

Answer (score 1):

I think that works. $\phi:H\to G$ by:

$\phi(0)=c,\phi(1)=a,\phi(2)=f,\phi(3)=e,\phi(4)=i,\phi(5)=b,\phi(6)=g,\phi(7)=h,\phi(8)=d$ $\phi(9)=j$.

Comment: She wanted to know how to *find* such a $\phi$. – By the way, your $\phi$ maps $H$ onto $G$.

Comment: It's pretty hard to explain here. All the vertices have the same rank so the only way I see is define $\phi(1)=a$, then conclude what values I might give to the neighbors of $1$, then go to their neighbors and so on.